# Laravel 5.2, Maximum function nesting level

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Please, help me to find what is going on.
I just set up a basic Laravel project. It's a new fresh Laravel project (5.2.29)

This is route.php

```
Route::get('/', 'TestController@index');
```

This is the test controller

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

The home.blade.php is the one that comes with a fresh Laravel installation, the one printing "Laravel 5".

When I add the 'web' middleware, as following

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'TestController@index');
});
```

I get this error: "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!".
I read some thread about xDebug, so i add this line to xdebug.ini

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
```

but nothing changed.

Any help? Or any suggestion on what else could I check?
Thank you

Comment: Do compose update and see if that works.

Comment: did you restart the webserver after change? (apache, nginx, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove `web` middleware, because now it applies automatically to all routes. So, since v5.2.27 you do not need to apply `web` middleware to avoid errors.

Comment: Ok, that is the problem. My framework version is 5.2.29 so "web" middleware is applied by default. Thank you a lot.
Anyway, this is really surprising to me. Such a big update through minor releases will lead to break my application. What if I had this application in production and ran an upgrade?

Maybe it's offtopic, bot how do you face this? Do you often run a framework upgrade or skip upgrades to avoid these problems?
Or else: how do you keep up-to-date with every single change between minor releases? On Laravel website I can find only major releases changelog.

Comment: When you're asking about updating Laravel, I'd recommend to do not update it if you already have pretty big app. Laravel developers broke backward compatibility a lot of times (Symfony developers, for example, do not do that). I know one really huge website which still use really really really old phpbb2 version, developers do not update for same reason.

Comment: Thanks. ) Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed new application (5.2.27 at the moment of installation), you don't have to use `web` middleware group because it will be automatically applied, however if you installed version prior to 5.2.27 and then updated to 5.2.27 or later you still need to use it.

So first you need to verify `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` if there's web middleware group automatically applied. If yes, you should remove it from `routes.php` because you might get unexpected behaviour.

If it's not the case, you should verify what Middleware are included into `web` middleware group because some of them might cause problems